# Connecting to SDL Tridion WebDAV via Windows Explorer (Windows 2008 R2)

Tags: tridion

I'm having difficulty mapping a WebDAV network location within Windows Explorer, to my local SDL Tridion 2011 SP1 website.  I'm working on the CME server, which is running on Windows 2008 R2.  I don't have office tools installed on the machine to try and test the WebDAV connection, is there something else I need?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably need to install the Desktop Experience feature to make this work from the server. See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772567.aspx for details

Answer (score 6):

Did installation of the Desktop Experience work?

I can connect through Word but not through mapped drive (and not through Content Porter)

- that said we had to change the MTSUser (machine) password (had changed the COM+ login) but as I see we have a number of NETWORK SERVICE issues in the security event we're reverting the password/login and restarting to confirm this is all OK first...

Comment: Desktop Experience was confirmed to be the answer, if it is already installed you can double check if the WebClient service is running, that is (or is related to) the WebDAV client.

Comment: Thanks Bart - I'll have someone check - I'm aware there were issues reported in the log to the effect of `2012-03-30 12:16:33,758 DEBUG AbstractHTTPHealthMonitor - TMA-PO-00000 Service WebDAV -  Setting credentials for NTLM Authentication
12:16:37,758 INFO  AbstractHTTPHealthMonitor - TMA-PO-10001 Service WebDAV - Health check failed: HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
12:16:39,742 DEBUG HealthCheckResultEventHandler - TMA-PO-00000 HealthCheckResultEventHandler - Updating status for WebDAV with id 2
12:16:39,742 INFO  ServiceStatusStore - TMA-AG-99999 Status of service 'WebDAV' changed to Error`